# how to crawl particular website using Apache Nutch?

Tags: apache, nutch

**i have followed below url** and done successfully till **Step-by-Step: Invertlinks**

https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#Crawl_your_first_website

**But i didn't get any data regarding them**

i am new to this techno,

please give **steps/demo/site/example** if someone has done it before successfully.
And
please do not give rough steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install the nutch:

**under configuration of nutch-site.xml, paste:**

```
<property>
    <name>http.agent.name</name>
    <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
</property>
```

**Under your nutch-default.xml: add**

```
<property>
  <name>http.robot.rules.whitelist</name>
  <value>http://nihilent.com/</value>
  <description>Comma separated list of hostnames or IP addresses to ignore
  robot rules parsing for. Use with care and only if you are explicitly
  allowed by the site owner to ignore the site's robots.txt!
  </description>
</property>
```

**Under regex-urlfilter.txt** :

```
# accept anything else
+.
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*http://nihilent.com/
```

**and also comment the**

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
#-[?*!@=]
```

**then run the below commands**

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments
s1=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s1
bin/nutch fetch $s1
bin/nutch parse $s1
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1

bin/nutch invertlinks crawl/linkdb -dir crawl/segments
```

Now check your data  in the crawl/crawldb folder & other successfully.

Comment: haha, I liked your style asking question & answering question by own.

Comment: Yeah But i think differently, If i get solution of my problem, I used to drop my solution so someone else will not suffer.

Comment: +Lokesh Kakran very less number of person thinks like that, Great sir .

Answer (score 0):

Below are few commands which will help you while doing Nutch in various ways

- These command contains direct crwaling on console , big data reading dumpin etc
- I am mentioning all available command which i had done please modify as per your requirements

### Commands Nutch

> ```
> bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz
> bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
> bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments
> s4=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
> echo $s1
> bin/nutch fetch $s1
> bin/nutch parse $s1
> bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1
> ```

```
bin/nutch invertlinks crawl/linkdb -dir crawl/segments

bin/nutch commoncrawldump -outputDir hdfs://localhost:9000/dfs -segment /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/ -jsonArray -reverseKey -SimpleDateFormat -epochFilename

bin/nutch readseg -dump /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments/ /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/ndeploy/1

bin/nutch readseg -get /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/segments http://1465212304000.html -nofetch -nogenerate -noparse -noparsedata -noparsetext
```

> bin/nutch parsechecker -dumpText http://nihilent.com/

```
bin/nutch readlinkdb /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/crawl/linkdb -dump /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/ndeploy/Data/Team-A/fileLinkedIn/3

bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -dump /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/ndeploy/Data/Team-A/fileLinkedIn

bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -dump /hdfs://localhost:9000/dfs

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/lokesh_Kumar/soft/apache-nutch-1.11/ndeploy/data/commoncrawl/com hdfs://localhost:9000/dfs
```

---

added new answer just because of avoid sandwich data